# What does the comma mean in the mathematical expression?

Tags: notation, fourier-transform

While reading the [Wikipedia page on Fourier-transform spectroscopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier-transform_spectroscopy), in the section "Extracting the spectrum", I found the following

$$ I(p) = \bigg(p, \int_0^\infty I(p, v) \, {\rm d} v\bigg) = \bigg(p,  \int_0^\infty I(v)(1+\cos(2 \pi v p) \, {\rm d} v \bigg)$$

where

- $I(p)$ is the total intensity at the detector
- $v$ is the wave number
- $I(v)$ is the spectrum to be determined
- $p$ the path length difference

Could someone please explain to me what the comma after the $p$ here means?

Comment: Please don't use pictures for text.
See [here](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text), why.
Use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). It looks like  the comma is for denoting pairs $(a,b)$. You need to give more context on $I(p)$.

Comment: Hi thanks, but how can an integral be a variable of a function?

Comment: I can say I haven’t seen that before. Also the $dv$ belongs inside the parenthesis.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to me....

Comment: I agree that it's confusing, and the suggestions that "Intensity is an ordered pair", and "this denotes a function of two variable" make no sense to me in that context.

Comment: Is it an inner product?

Comment: It also would not make any sense...

Comment: Instead of a pair of values, it should be just the integral.

Comment: so just ignoring the p and I(v) = only the integral ?

Comment: I believe so. It does not make sense otherwise. You may look at https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Spectroscopy/Fundamentals_of_Spectroscopy/The_Power_of_the_Fourier_Transform_for_Spectroscopists

Comment: oh nice indeed ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: According to the article's history log, the extra $p$ and the comma were added to the Wikipedia page in [an edit at 1:29 on November 28, 2012](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Fourier-transform_spectroscopy&diff=525243887&oldid=525242291). I can't find any reason given for the change.

Comment: Thanks, @DavidK. I could not access the history on my phone, and was dying to know how it got in there. Apinorr, I think you should edit back the Wikipedia page.

Comment: I edited back the Wikipedia page. (The only other contributions by the wp-user who made the original edit were similarly confused.)

Comment: Is it `v` ($v$) or `\nu`($\nu$)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summing up the comments: The $p$:s and commas before the integral signs stem from [an unexplained Wikipedia edit](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Fourier-transform_spectroscopy&diff=525243887&oldid=525242291) from 2012. They appear to have no meaning, and have now been removed from the Wikipedia article.